# How CLR works when invoking a method of a struct

Tags: c#, .net, clr, value-type, il

I think I've known the answer for a class, just want to confirm my understanding is correct. Let's say I have a `ClassA` and its instance named `a`. When `a.MethodA()` is invoked:

(1) CLR find the type of `ClassA` by the *type pointer* of `a` in the heap(the type have been loaded into the heap)

(2) Find the `MethodA` in the type, if not found, go to its base type, until the `object` class.

Maybe my understanding is not quite precise, but I think it's basicly correct(Correct me if it's wrong!). And here comes the question of a simple *struct*.

```
struct MyStruct
{
   public void MethodA() { }
}
```

I have `var x = new MyStruct();`, its value is on the stack, and the type of `MyStruct` has been loaded into the heap. When execute `x.MethodA()`, of course no boxing. How CLR find `MethodA` and get the IL and execute/JIT it? I think the answer is probably:(again, correct me if I'm wrong)

(1) we have the *declaring type* of `x` on the stack. CLR find its type by the info on the stack, and find `MethodA` in its type. -- let's call it `assumptionA`.

I'll be happy if you tell me my `assumptionA` is correct. But even it's wrong, it tells a truth: CLR has a way to find a struct's type without boxing.

Now what about `x.ToString()` or `x.GetType()`? We know that the value will be boxed, and then it will perform like a class. But why do we need boxing here? Since we can get its type(assumptionA tells us), why not go to its base type and find the method(just like a class)? Why need an expensive box operations here?

Comment: @Danny Chen, structs are not always allocated on the stack.  It is only allocated on the stack if it is 1) passed as value as argument to a method, 2) not part of a closure, and 3) not a large object.  Otherwise, it still got allocated on the heap.

Comment: @Stephen Chung: Thanks for your prompt. But in this case, it is, right?

Comment: Well, it is on the stack if it is a local variable, not large (doesn't seem to be) and not captured in a closure (so it depends on whether your code in this block contains a lambda).

Comment: @Stephen: Are you sure that large structs are allocated on the heap? I don't believe the size makes a difference...

Comment: @Mehrdad - objects > 85KB are always allocated on the "large objects heap" which is separate from the regular heap.  AFAIK structs > 85KB also fall into this category, but you're going to need to work at it to construct such a large struct...

Comment: It's hard to imagine how you'd create a struct larger than 85k! I can't imagine any normal object other than arrays in the LOH. Of course, the larger your struct is, the fewer elements you need in an array to make it into the LOH.

Comment: @Stephen, @Gabe: Not that hard.  It's easy to build a struct type whose size is exponentially related to the length of the source code.  A dozen lines of code should be enough.  `struct S1 { long a, b, c, d, e, f; } struct S2 { S1 a, b, c, d, e, f; } struct S3 { S2 a, b, c, d, e, f; } struct S4 { S3 a, b, c, d, e, f; } struct S5 { S4 a, b, c, d, e, f; } struct S6 { S5 a, b; }` and S6 is more than 85k.

Comment: @Stephen: Would you mind citing the source for this?

Comment: @Mehrdad, stack vs. heap: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx  (sorry this is the only one I find right away)

Comment: @Stephen: I don't see the number `85` anywhere in that page...

Comment: @Mehrdad, that is just on the issue of whether it is stored on the stack vs. heap.  85KB is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx

Comment: @Mehrdad, I am not so sure in the case when a struct > 85KB is allocated as a local variable in a method -- whether it will be on the stack or LOH.  Could be on the stack (because it will be thrown away when the method returns).  However, if it is captured in a closure, then it will be on the heap, and if it is > 85KB, then it will be in the LOH.

Comment: @Stephen: But that link says nothing about value types! It says that large `Object`s are placed on the LOH, but that doesn't refer to value types, only reference types... and *of course* it'd be on the heap if it's in a closure, but that's not what we were talking about. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad, you're probably right in that local variables of value types >85KB not captured by a closure is still allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AssumptionA is wrong.  The C# compiler's symbol table stores type information.  That static type information is used in nearly all cases, the dynamic type stored in an object is only needed during type checks (`is` operator), casting (`as` operator and actual cast syntax), and array variance, and then only when the dynamic type isn't known to the compiler.  The dynamic type of an unboxed struct is always statically known, and dynamic type of a class instance is statically known near the instantiation and inside a conditional block which performed a type check (e.g. in `if (x is T) y = (T)x;` the type is known inside the then-part, so the cast doesn't require another dynamic check).

Ok, now because the C# compiler statically knows the type of `x`, it can do overload resolution and find the *exact* MethodA being called.  Then it emits MSIL to push the arguments onto the MSIL virtual stack and issues a call instruction containing a metadata reference to that particular method.  No type checks are needed at runtime.

For `x.ToString()`, the C# compiler still knows the exact method it wants to call.  If `ToString` has been overridden by the `struct` type, it expects a parameter of type *pointer-to-`MyStruct`*, which the compiler handles without boxing.  If `ToString` has not been overridden, the compiler generates a call to `Object.ToString`, which expects an object as its parameter.  To push `x` on the MSIL virtual stack as the correct type requires boxing.

`GetType` is a special case when the type is known statically, the compiler won't call any method, it just gets the type information from the symbol table and stuffs the metadata reference into the MSIL directly.

Comment: It does not look like GetType is handled the way you describe at least at IL level...

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's a few different things going on here:

- For methods that are *defined in the struct*, the CLR just takes a look at the type definition in the assembly metadata when it's being loaded in order to figure out what the methods are, and when a method `Foo` calls `MethodA`, the CLR just binds to the correct method *when `MethodA` is JIT'd*. There's nothing else actually happening after the compilation has all taken place; the method is called directly, because any information that's needed is already present.
- For **virtual** <strike>inherited</strike> struct methods like `ToString`, <strike>there *has* to be boxing because virtual calls can only be called on `Object`s, by design -- without boxing, there's no v-table to look into in order to figure out the resulting method. (The fact that the method call might be immediately after the boxing *might* allow for potential optimizations, but it's a long shot -- I doubt the JIT compiler does this.)</strike> apparently there's no boxing; I was wrong because I didn't notice that these methods are overridden. Indeed, for overridden methods, the compiler *does* perform the optimization by just calling the method directly, because there's no reason not to. (There are *no* virtual methods for value types that are not overridden, so that's not actually an issue here.)
- For **non-virtual** struct methods that are *inherited*, the object needs to be boxed simply because the method is, by definition, being called on a reference type, not on a value type; there's no need to special-case this in the compiler, because I believe the JIT compiler can actually do optimizations (like avoiding boxing) when it's JIT'ing a method like `GetType` (though someone please correct me if I'm wrong about this optimization thing).

Comment: This is wrong, v-table lookups are never needed when the variable type is a struct.  If a struct has been boxed earlier (the call is made through a variable of type `object` or an interface) the v-table may be used.

Comment: @Ben: Never mind, you're right; my apologies, and thanks for pointing it out. :) I also missed the fact that these methods inherited from `Object` are *overridden* later, and yes, there's no need for a v-table lookup.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Thanks for comments. I thought that I understand how it works... not anymore. So I'll leave this as starting point for investigation, but not an answer.

There could be boxing for calling ToString or other virtual functions on structs because there is no need for v-table lookup. Structs are sealed, so exact method is known and compile time.

On other hand as pointed in comments virtual functions from base class need Object as "this" parameter.

On third hand looking at generated IL it is unclear if ToString and GetHashCode actually do boxing (likly it is hidden somewhere since there is comment about boxing in these cases here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucabol/archive/2007/12/24/creating-an-immutable-value-object-in-c-part-iii-using-a-struct.aspx). GetType definietly requires explicit boxing.

Looking at output of ILDasm to see if there is boxing or direct call:

```
       int v = 42;

        string s = v.ToString();

        object a = v;
        s = a.ToString();
```

Get compiled (debug) into following IL. There is no boxing for int.ToString(), but definitely  one for casting to object...

```
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s   42
  IL_0003:  stloc.0
  IL_0004:  ldloca.s   v
  IL_0006:  call       instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
  IL_000b:  stloc.1
  IL_0013:  ldloc.0
  IL_0014:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0019:  stloc.2
  IL_001a:  ldloc.2
  IL_001b:  callvirt   instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
  IL_0020:  stloc.1
```

Comment: Yes and no.  There is no v-table lookup, since the type is known statically.  But, if the method is inherited from `Object` and not overridden in the struct, it expects a `this` parameter of type `Object`.  Which means the struct will be boxed.

Comment: I thought I understood this too, but I was wrong (thanks for your answer, it really helped!) and *now* I think I get it: *non* -virtual methods require boxing (since they require an `Object`), but *virtual* methods don't, because it just so happens that they're all overridden already down the hierarchy, so they're really called directly on the value type. (Hope I'm not missing anything here...)