# Preventing creation of the of virtual method table in C++

Tags: c#, c++

In C# structures being value types may implement interfaces with all its benefits without size overhead, look at this snippet:

```
interface IMove
{
    void Move(Int32 l);
}

struct Point : IMove
{
    public Int32 x;
    public Int32 y;

    public void Move(Int32 l)
    {
        this.x += l;
        this.y += l;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Int32))); // Prints "4"
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Point))); // Prints "8"
    }
}
```

But when I try to implement this in C++ the size of the structure becomes larger:

```
#include <iostream>

class IMove
{
    public:
    virtual void move(int l) = 0;
};

class Point : public IMove
{
    public:
    int x;
    int y;

    void move(int l)
    {
        this->x += l;
        this->y += l;
    }
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << sizeof(int) << "\n"; // Prints "4"
  std::cout << sizeof(Point) << "\n"; // Prints "12"
}
```

I think it's because of the pointer to the virtual method table. Is it possible to implement similar functionality without overhead in object size?

Comment: Yup, don't have virtual methods. Easy peasy!

Comment: Why do you think the marshalled size (and layout) is all that closely coupled to the managed size and layout?

Comment: Of course the size you are printing in C# is absolutely not the size of your actual object - just the size of the content, so your C# object will certainly HAVE a vtable - you just can't see it because of the magicians handkerchief - just like the rabbit that he pulls out of the hat, it was there all the time, you just couldn't see it.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Hmm... Is there a way to get the _actual_ size of the object to verify this?

Comment: @Menzoda Why do you even care so much? Are you running out of RAM?

Comment: You can do this without any inheritance on the `Point` class: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil

Comment: @chris I want to pass this object (Point) to a function that takes the interface (IMove) as parameter.

Comment: @MatsPetersson c# structs don't have a viable, the size is correct. The compiler is not lying about it

Comment: So, you need a vtable if you are going to pass it to something that takes an `IMove` object... There are no two ways about it, the `IMove` object has a VTable, and your `Point` object also needs one. If you don't want to do that, then don't pass it to a function that takes an `IMove` type, and then you don't need a vtable. However, you can fit an awful lot of 12 byte objects in any modern computer - if I used up all my machines memory, it would be 1.3 billion of them. That's quite a large number. Even in my laptop some 0.6 billion is quite a number.

Comment: @oefe: And no OTHER data stored with/next-to the object? Does C# not support virtual functions then? Or is it magiced in some other way? [I admit, I don't know how C# works, but I have a hard time believing that it doesn't support virtual functions, which means that there must be SOME kind of extra information beyond the actual data to give those virtual function pointers]

Comment: @MatsPetersson objects *do* have vtables

Comment: @BaummitAugen 4 bytes overhead of one object is nothing, but if you need 1000000 objects it begins to be felt. Besides there is embedded systems where 1M of RAM is unaffordable luxury.

Comment: @Menzoda, And you can with that technique. By value even.

Comment: @chris Okay, I will take a closer look at it.

Comment: @Menzoda Sure there are, but if you do not target them, you could spend your day with nicer things unless you just want to know if/how it could be done. Even if you need 1000000 objects, that's 4 MB of RAM, so still nothing on a normal PC.

Comment: @oefe: And you can have a struct instance that is not an object in C# [and do something useful with it]? Or is the "difference between struct and object instance" another one of those magicians handkerchiefs ["it is not part of the struct, so therefore it only exists when you instantiate the object" is not "it doesn't have one", it is "it's not part of the struct, but one exists with every struct instance created" - maybe a politician will make that into doesn't exist, but in my mind they go together]

Comment: @MatsPetersson I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494807/how-clr-works-when-invoking-a-method-of-a-struct) touches a similar theme. As I understand, C# compiler is quite smart (smarter than C++?) to resolve some issues statically and automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want the overhead of storing the extra v-table pointer, you can always use a wrapper object before passing the point as an IMove:

```
struct Point { int x; int y; };

struct MoveablePoint : public IMove {
    Point& point;
    MovablePoint(Point& point) : point(point) {}
    virtual void move(int l) { point.x += l; point.y += l; }
};
```

Example usage:

```
Point point = {0};
MovablePoint movablePoint(point);
doSomething(movablePoint);
```

Now there's no need to store the v-table in point when you need it to persist.

Comment: So, as per usual, this becomes a tradeoff between performance and memory space, since constructing a MovabePoint will have some overhead.

Comment: @MatsPetersson The overhead you are referring to involves copying two pointers on the stack. If you are that concerned about performance you should probably skip the interface altogether.

Comment: And dereferencing point through a reference rather than direcetly. And you may not have a choice for skipping the interface (without rewriting lots of code, and that may not actually be beneficial anyway - virtual methods are fairly efficient in general - compared to other methods that offer similar fleixibility - if you only have one method on one type of object, sure it can be quicker)

Comment: @MatsPetersson I guarantee you that the cost of copying two pointers and dereferencing the point is small compared to the cost of a virtual function call. In short, dynamic dispatch is really bad for branch prediction.

Answer (score 1):

There is Curiously Recurring Template Pattern to separate interface and implementation, no vtable needed

```
template <typename ToMove> struct Moveable
{
    void move()
    {
        static_cast<ToMove*>(this)->move_implementation();
    }
};

struct Point : Moveable<Point>
{
    void move_implementation()
    {
        cout << "Moving...\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: In this example, there's no non-template base class. In short, you can't define a non-template function that takes a generic Movable*. It must take a Movable<T>* of a certain type, T.