# How to check if a generic parameter is not null without boxing

Tags: c#, generics, interface, overloading, boxing

I want to write a method that accepts a single `IBar` and call its `Baz` method.

This throws when `obj` is null:

```
void Foo<T>(T obj)
    where T : IBar
    => obj.Baz();
```

This boxes `obj` when it is a value type:

```
void Foo<T>(T obj)
    where T : IBar
    => obj?.Baz();
```

This doesn't call `Baz` if `obj` is zero:

```
void Foo<T>(T obj)
    where T : IBar
{
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(obj, default(T)))
        obj.Baz();
}
```

And here, `Foo(new Bar())` always picks the generic method no matter if `Bar` is a class or struct:

```
void Foo<T>(T obj)
    where T : struct, IBar
    => obj.Baz();

void Foo(IBar obj)
    => obj?.Baz();
```

This makes my eyes bleed:

```
void FooVal<T>(T obj)
    where T : struct, IBar
    => obj.Baz();

void FooRef(IBar obj)
    => obj?.Baz();
```

So is there a best practice for this? I'm open to all suggestions.

Edit:

The question is marked as duplicate with [Generic constraints, where T : struct and where T : class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2974519/704144) and with the old title, it was. So I've updated the title to convey my problem better. What I'm asking is that how can I call a generic method and use the argument *only if it is not null, without boxing.*

Some workarounds explained for the linked question *may be used* to answer this one but I still believe this is a fundamentally different question.

Comment: Only a reference type (class) can ever be null. A value type (struct) can never be null (and using null for ``Nullable<T>`` is just syntactic sugar). On the other hand, a struct may be boxed for the purpose of invoking an instance method; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494807 for a discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this helper:

```
public static class Null
{
    public static bool IsNull<T>(T obj) => !Data<T>.HasValue(obj);

    private static class Data<T>
    {
        public static readonly Func<T, bool> HasValue = InitHasValue();

        private static Func<T, bool> InitHasValue()
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            if (!type.IsValueType)
                return obj => obj != null;

            if (type.IsGenericType &&
                type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                var value = Expression.Parameter(type, "value");
                var getter = type.GetProperty("HasValue").GetMethod;
                var call = Expression.Call(value, getter);
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, value);
                return lambda.Compile();
            }

            return obj => true;
        }
    }
}
```

So I can do this:

```
void Foo<T>(T obj)
    where T : IBar
{
    if (!Null.IsNull(obj)) // Does not box.
        obj.Baz();
}
```

Comment: What was the problem with boxing?

Comment: I ask because I still see a box instruction in the `false` branch of that ternary expression.

Comment: Nothing in this example but it's undesirable to make unnecessary allocations if the method gets called a lot (in a tight loop, for example).

Comment: I suspect it is in the initialization of `IsNull` field (one-time) and not whenever `Foo` is called? Edit: Sorry, the false branch is for reference types so that wouldn't cause an allocation afaik.

Answer (score 2):

Having just had a similar problem, I came up with the following solution:

```
void Foo<T>(T obj)
{
  if (obj is object)
    obj.Baz();
}
```

The result of the `is` operation is always `false` if `obj` is null or a nullable type with a value of `null`, and if not it checks whether a boxing conversion from `T` to `object` exists, which is always the case.

Unless the compiler is not optimizing at all, this should in effect end up being just a `null` check, or a noop for non-nullable types.

Comment: `obj is object` is optimised by the compiler by `obj != null` (which is a natural choice) and because T does not have any constraint, a boxing occurs before the check happens hence invalidating this proposition